# How to add an object multiple times in different tables with Entity Framework Core [Tracking error]

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

To simplify, I have a "Project" type that can contain several "Manager" and several "Employee". Each Employee and Manager is composed of an "Id" and "Person" property.

```
        public class Project
        {
            ...
            public ObservableCollection<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
            public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        }

        public class Manager
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public Person Person { get; set; }
        }

        public class Employee
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public Person Person { get; set; }
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

I retrieve the information about a project from the database in the following way:

```
Project project = context.Set<Project>()
                .Include(p => proj.Managers).ThenInclude(d => d.Person)
                .Include(p => proj.Employees).ThenInclude(e => e.Person)
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
```

When I want to modify the Employees participating in the project I select the employee from a list of Persons

```
List<Person> Persons = context.Set<Person>().AsNoTracking().ToList();
...
theCurrentProject.Employees.Add(new Employee{ Person = theSelectedPerson});
```

Then when I call context.SaveChanges();, if the Person is already present in the list of Managers and I also add it to the Employees the following error occurs: The instance of type 'Person' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id:x}' is already being tracked.

I'm doing something wrong but I can't see what. I understand that at the time of loading the information from the database the different "Persons" present in the project are "Tracked" by EF and therefore the person that comes from the list of Persons is not the same as the one already beeing tracked. That's why I tried to add AsNoTracking() but without success. "Persons" are read-only in this software (I don't need the tracking on them). How can I make this work ?  And also possibly how to tell EF that such or such object is read-only and that it should not try to modify (track) them?
I have tried 4-5 different approaches but none of them solves my problem.
thanks in advance !

Comment: No reason to ADD a new employee.  Try :theCurrentProject.Employees.Add(theSelectedPerson};

Comment: I got the folowing error: "Cannot convert from Person to Employee"

Comment: Is Employee ID and Person ID the same?  You need to get the employee object for the person and then add the employee without a new Employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var employee=new Employee{ PersonId = theSelectedPerson.Id};

 context.Set<Employees>.Add(employee);
 context.SaveChanges();

// get saved employee

var savedEmployee = context.Set<Employees>()
.Include (p=>p.Person)
.AsNoTracking()
.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.Id=employee.Id);

//or

var savedEmployee = context.Set<Employees>()
.Include (p=>p.Person)
.AsNoTracking()
.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.PersonId=theSelectedPerson.Id);
```

but  before this you have to fix the bug in the classes

```
public class Manager
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int PersonId { get; set; }
            public Person Person { get; set; }
        }

        public class Employee
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int PersonId { get; set; }
            public Person Person { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I added PersonId and now I don't get the tracking error. But by inserting only the PersonId in the new Employee the Person property is null until context.SaveChange() is called. So I can't read the Name property of the Person object until context.SaveChange() is called. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: This way it is supposed to be. I don't see any problem.  You have already theSelectedPerson. What else do you need for?

Comment: @Bruno I made some updates. Pls let  me know if it is helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for your help, indeed it works perfectly. I will work with the Id's from now on.